# NSDateFormatter returning nil

Tags: objective-c, nsdateformatter

can anyone please tell me why this code snippet returns nil in my log file:

```
    NSString *dateString = [[NSString alloc] initWithString: @"2011-08-23 15:00"];

NSLocale *englishLocale = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en"];
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"YYYY-mm-dd HH:MM"];
[dateFormatter setLocale:englishLocale];

NSLog(@"%@",[dateFormatter dateFromString:dateString]);
```

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check my variant:

```
NSString *dateString = [[NSString alloc] initWithString: @"2011-08-23 15:00"];

NSLocale *englishLocale = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en"];
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
//HH:MM -> HH:mm
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm"];
[dateFormatter setLocale:englishLocale];

NSLog(@"%@",[dateFormatter dateFromString:dateString]);
```

As you see I've changed date format to : `@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm"`

All formats can be found here: [UNICODE LOCALE DATA MARKUP LANGUAGE (LDML)](http://unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-10.html#Date_Format_Patterns)

Answer (score 3):

you should be correct 'HH:MM' to 'HH:mm'

```
NSString *dateString = [[NSString alloc] initWithString: @"2011-08-23 15:00"];

    NSLocale *englishLocale = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en"];
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    //HH:MM -> HH:mm
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm"];
    [dateFormatter setLocale:englishLocale];

    NSLog(@"%@",[dateFormatter dateFromString:dateString]);
```

Comment: Is this due to the NSLocale settings?

Comment: It's summer time, and the living is easy... (i.e., yes)

Comment: Sorry. I've a mistake. ^^. i too modified.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.picksourcecode.com/ps/ct/161110.php

For more dateFormats